# Node redirects to repeating URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to redirect if the user enters a certain URL (for redirecting from a Heroku domain).

When I test this on `localhost` I get the redirect URL repeated:

```
http://localhost:5000/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/www.daniel-knights.me/
```

First time I've tried redirecting from Node so I have no idea why or how it's doing this.

Code for the redirect:

```
app.use(function forceLiveDomain(req, res, next) {
    const host = req.get("Host");

    if (host === "localhost:5000") {
        return res.redirect(301, "www.daniel-knights.me" + req.originalUrl);
    }

    return next();
});
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the proper URL, with protocol.

```
return res.redirect(301, 'https://www.daniel-knights.me' + req.originalUrl);
```

Otherwise, the browser will assume you're redirecting to a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding protocol here, and due to this browser stuck in a loop since it just understands the relative URL if you do not provide the protocol.

```
res.redirect(301, 'http://www.daniel-knights.me' + req.originalUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use absolute url instead of relative url while redirecting.